# Add serial numbers to a column in csv in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

[image]I'm reading a CSV file in Apache Nifi and now i want to add a column which is serial number and this column will have the serial number for all the rows in the CSV file. So if i have 10 rows the serial number would from 1 to 10.How can i achieve this through Nifi?
I've tried using getStateValue in the update processor but this gives me a static number. My UpdateAttribute and UpdateRecord are shown below.[image]

Comment: share your code please

Comment: do want the xml code?

Comment: anything that can help people coming to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [QueryRecord](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html) processor and processor supports [Apache-Calcite SQL language](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html).

Add **`new dynamic property`** to QueryRecord processor by using `ROW_NUMBER()` window clause.

***Example:***

```
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(<optional orderby clause>) as seq from FLOWFILE
```

Define `RecordReader` and **`RecordWriter`** controller services in query record processor to include **`seq column`** in `avro schema`.

Output flowfile from **`queryrecord`** processor now will include `seq column` to the flowfile.